# exposing jQuery plugin properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following JQuery plugin.  Is it possible to expose the variable 'elements' to javascript external to the plugin?  And if so, how is this done?  For javascript external to this plugin, what would the syntax be to access 'elements'?

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

        // I WANT TO EXPOSE THIS AS A 'PUBLIC' PROPERTY OF THIS PLUGIN
        var elements = {};

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.selector').myPlugin();
​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(function($) {
   $.myPlugin = {
       elements: {}
   };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

To expose `elements` as an instance property change `var elements` to `this.elements`:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    this.elements = {};

    return this;
};
```

Just found the following post that discusses the topic in more detail:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff608209